# Правильно ли построено предложение?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Правильно ли построено предложение:

> Тогда на пересечении Губернаторской улицы и Соборной площади было воздвигнуто здание новой гостиницы Минска, которое имело 2 этажа, но не имела названия.

Answer (score 1):

1. "здание гостиницы Минска"

Если речь идёт о том, что в Минске была построена гостиница, то так сказать нельзя: это  выражение подходит только для единственного в городе учреждения (напр. "мэрия Минска"). Возможно "минская гостиница" или " гостиница в Минске".

2. "Имело... но не имела..." - нельзя отнести придаточные предложения к двум частям составного понятия "здание гостиницы", не разделив его.

Можно, например, так:

... в Минске было воздвигнуто двухэтажное здание гостиницы, не получившей названия.

Answer (score 0):

Все нормально. А что у вас вызвало сомнение?

Answer (score 0):

Теперь это пятизвёздочный отель «Европа» в центре Минска

"Построен он был на заре девятнадцатого века, когда Минск был частью Российской Империи. Тогда на пересечении Губернаторской улицы и Соборной площади было воздвигнуто здание новой гостиницы Минска, которое имело 2 этажа, но не имела названия".

Это рекламный текст на сайте этой гостиницы ("гостиницы Минска"  подчеркнуто как ссылка). Но лучше написать "новой двухэтажной гостиницы, которая в то время так и не получила названия".

Comment: Ох, не видел Вашего... Vera, я крепко сомневаюсь, что речь идет о том же **здании**. Я, конечно, не минчанин, но помнится, Соборная (ныне - Свободы) после войны была просто заново построена... Да и нынешнее современное пяти- (или шести?) этажное здание отлеля "Европа" находится несколько в стороне от ул. Ленина, только фасадом выходя на пл. Свободы.

Comment: Я никогда, к сожалению, не была в Минске и всего лишь нашла этот текст в Интернете. http://www.hoteleurope.by/about_hotel/history/

Answer (score 0):

Безусловная грамматическая ошибка здесь одна.

Тогда... было воздвигнуто здание новой гостиницы Минска, которое **имело** 2 этажа, но не **имела** названия."

Если "имела название" относится к гостинице, не к зданию (а иное предположить трудно), то нет союзного слова "которая". Это слово просто так вставить не получается, мешает удаленность от определяемого слова гостиница, что усугубляется наличием другого подчиненного между гостиницей и "не имела".

Думаю, что в предложении проще всего пожертвовать союзом "но". В нем нет большого смысла, почему этажность здания как-то противопоставляется наличию названия? 
Поэтому грамматика будет соблюдена и смысл не пострадает, если написать

**Тогда на пересечении Губернаторской улицы и Соборной площади было воздвигнуто здание новой *двухэтажной* гостиницы Минска, которая не имела названия.**

Теперь по смыслу.
~1. Надо понимать, что "Минск" тут город, а не название гостиницы (которое было присвоено позже). Иначе было бы гостиницы "Минск", но фразу пришлось бы перестраивать, ибо в таком случае формулировка "не имела названия" стало бы совсем непонятным.
~2. К "пересечению" улицы и площадии я отношусь с большой настороженностью. такое возможно только для очень протяженной, вытянутой площади, которую *пересекает* улица. Если речь о минских Площади Свободы и ул. Ленина, я такого бы не употреблял. Может, лучше, "на углу"? Или что-то подобное?
~3. Я не согласен, что "новая гостиница Минска" может относиться только к одной гостиницы в городе. Хотя шут его знает, о каких временах речь, иожет тогда она и одна была, не могу судить, знаю Минск, но уже, как понимаете, послевоенный, а там от старой застройки кроме Троицкого предместья ничего ж не осталось... Тут другое. Если гостиница была частной, не принадлежала городской Думе (или как там назывался орган местного самоуправления во времена, о которых повествуется), то "гостиница Минска" двусмысленно, хотя и не уверен, что неправильно.
Тем не менее, могу предложить компромисс "здание новой *городской* гостиницы". Хотя и тут надо крепко подумать - и уточнить, была ли сия гостиница действительно городской.